How to Read a Zip Folder from AWS and Show the Contents in Laravel?
I have a problem. I have a lot of zip folders in Amazon Storage.
I want to show the list of those folders on one page in Laravel. Then, when I click on one of those zip folders, I want to go to a new page that shows the content of the zip folder without saving it to my local storage because the size of the folders is so huge.
I tried showing them in a href tag:
<a href="myfolder.zip">See Folder</a>
The result of that makes the zip folder download to my local storage.
How can I do that in Laravel? I also use jQuery/JavaScript for fetching data.
Is there any chance to open the zip if the zip is from the local?

You cannot do it without download it from s3.

is there any chance to open zip if the zip is from the local?

Temporarily save the zip file locally to handle it.
$zipFile = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), 's3zip');
file_put_contents($zipFile, $zipStream);

Using ZipArchive, open the zip file and read its contents. Each file name inside the zip is stored in an array.
$zip = new ZipArchive;
if ($zip->open($zipFile) === TRUE) {
    $contents = [];
    for ($i = 0; i < $zip->numFiles; i++) {
        $contents[] = $zip->getNameIndex($i);
    }
    $zip->close();
    unlink($zipFile); // Clean up the temporary file
} else {
    return "Failed to open the zip file.";
}

Fetch the zip file from S3, You can't read the file contents directly from S3
